# Unable to import table from Mysql to HDFS using sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

**Current setup**

1. mysql connector version-mysql-connector-java-5.1.46
2. sqoop version-sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0
3. hadoop version-hadoop-2.7.5
4. java version- Jdk-8u171-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_171(oracle JDK)
5. OS-Ubundu

> hadoop running in local mode single node

**Note:** Also tried with openjdk , same issue exist with this version also

> **Sqoop Command :**  bin/sqoop import -connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDb -username root -password root
>   --table student --target-dir /user/hadoop/student -m 1

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Looks like you didn't add HADOOP_HOME to the your sqoop-env (java classes can't be found)

Comment: Keep in mind that `sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0` means it's been built / tested with Hadoop 2.6, not necessarily 2.7

Comment: I am getting below error, I have configured sqoop version 1.4.6